# The Active Directory Membership Provider has not been initialized when trying to access user information

Tags: c#, asp.net

First time trying to use AD authentication in a ASP.NET web application. When trying to get basic information about the user by using the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` class I am getting an error stating `The Active Directory Membership Provider has not been initialized.`

Here is my web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="ADService" connectionString ="LDAP://AMAZON-A923C5B1.l5.chm.com/" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, 
                 System.Web, Version=2.0.3600, Culture=neutral, 
                 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             connectionStringName="ADService"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Here is my code:

```
    ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider();

    if (this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {

        MembershipUser user = provider.GetUser(this.Page.User.Identity.Name, true);

        LoginName loginName = HeadLoginView.FindControl("HeadLoginName") as LoginName;
        loginName.FormatString = user.UserName;
    }
}
```

Here is my error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
provider.Initialize("NameOfYourProvider", NameValueCollectionOfConfigOptions)
```

Where "NameValueCollectionOfConfigOptions" is a `NameValueCollection`.

Comment: According to MSDN, "This method is not intended to be called from your code". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.initialize.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The class you are looking for is `System.Web.Security.Membership`.  The class exposes `GetUser` as a Static member.

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(this.Page.User.Identity.Name, true);
```

I don't think the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` class is meant to be used directly. From the documentation,

> This class is used by the Membership and MembershipUser classes to provide membership services for an ASP.NET application using an Active Directory (AD) or Active Directory Application Mode (ADAM) server.